# ASP.NET MVC 5 : no IUserTokenProvider is registered when sending forgot password email

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, simple-injector

I'm trying to send a reset password email, but I keep receiving the error

> No IUserTokenProvider is registered

on the line

```
string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
```

I think the issue is with `Simple Injector` and how I'm doing the registration?  In `ApplicationUserManager` I have the line

```
manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User, long>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
```

and it's being called, but when I set a breakpoint in the `ForgotPassword` method, the `UserTokenProvider` is `null`.

My account controller looks like this:

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IUserAuditCommand userAuditCommand, IUserViewModelBuilder builder, IMapper mapper)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    _userAuditCommand = userAuditCommand;
    _mapper = mapper;
    _builder = builder;
    _emailClient = new EmailClient();
}

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);

        if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user either does not exist or is not confirmed.");
            return View();
        }

         // Send an email with this link
         string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
         var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);     
         await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
         return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

ApplicationUserManager:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<User, long>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationUserStore store) : base(store) { }

    private const int PASSWORD_HISTORY_LIMIT = 5;

    public override async Task<IdentityResult> ChangePasswordAsync(long userId, string currentPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        if (await IsPreviousPassword(userId, newPassword))
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Failed("Cannot reuse old password"));
        }

        var result = await base.ChangePasswordAsync(userId, currentPassword, newPassword);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var store = Store as ApplicationUserStore;

            await store.AddToPreviousPasswordsAsync(await FindByIdAsync(userId), PasswordHasher.HashPassword(newPassword));
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override async Task<IdentityResult> ResetPasswordAsync(long userId, string token, string newPassword)
    {
        if (await IsPreviousPassword(userId, newPassword))
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Failed("Cannot reuse old password"));
        }

        var result = await base.ResetPasswordAsync(userId, token, newPassword);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var store = Store as ApplicationUserStore;

            await store.AddToPreviousPasswordsAsync(await FindByIdAsync(userId), PasswordHasher.HashPassword(newPassword));
        }

        return result;
    }

    private async Task<bool> IsPreviousPassword(long userId, string newPassword)
    {
        var store = Store as ApplicationUserStore;
        // List<PreviousPassword> passwords = await store.PreviousPasswords(userId);
        var user = await FindByIdAsync(userId);

        var query = user.PreviousPasswords.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate).Take(PASSWORD_HISTORY_LIMIT);
        query = query.Where(x => PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(x.Password, newPassword) != PasswordVerificationResult.Failed);

        if (query.Any())
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(context.Get<IdentityContext>()));

        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 3;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;

        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User, long>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = false,
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 8,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider(
            "PhoneCode",
            new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<User, long>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
            });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider(
            "EmailCode",
            new EmailTokenProvider<User, long>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
            });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        //manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;

        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User, long>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }

        return manager;
    }
}
```

SimpleInjectorInitializer:

```
container.Register<HttpContextBase>(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
container.Register(() => new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(container.GetInstance<IdentityContext>())), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Error Message:

```
No IUserTokenProvider is registered.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: No IUserTokenProvider is registered.

Source Error (Line 274 highlighted):
Line 272:                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
Line 273:                // Send an email with this link
Line 274:                 string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
Line 275:                 var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);        
Line 276:                 await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

    Stack Trace:
    [NotSupportedException: No IUserTokenProvider is registered.]
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<GenerateUserTokenAsync>d__127.MoveNext() +639
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +29
       ILETSB.OfficerPortal.UI.Controllers.<ForgotPassword>d__21.MoveNext() in C:\Users\aoldfield\source\repos\ILETSB.OfficerPortal\ILETSB.OfficerPortal.UI\Controllers\AccountController.cs:274
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +58
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +35
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
       System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
       System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
       System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) +161
       System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +128
```

Comment: Did you go through [this tutorial](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/597)?

Comment: And please update your question and include *all details of the exception you are getting*. Exception type name, message, and stack trace of the exception and all (possible) inner exception. Please post it as text (no images).

Comment: I updated the post with the full details.  I'm looking at the tutorial now, that's an older version of Simple Injector so I'm not sure if it'll still work.

Comment: This is unrelated to Simple Injector. Inside your `ApplicationUserManager.Create` method, you should initialize the `manager.UserTokenProvider` property. More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity).

Comment: I do, it's in the snippet above near the bottom of the code for the `ApplicationuserManager` class.  I set a breakpoint in that class and that line is being called with a value, but when I step through the code and get to the `AccountController` `manager.UserTokenProvider` is null.

Comment: No properties are being set for `UserManager` in the `AccountController`.  All properties that are set in the `Create` Method in `UserManager` are null in `AccountController`